# Is there a way to systematically ignore specific error messages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, forest

When I compile my documents with a lot of trees, I often get the following error code:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@xa 

l.1042 }}
```

This error is due to some temporary computation that `tikz` does (I use `forest`) and goes away after the next compilation of the document. So I would like to have some switch that turns such messages into warnings. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess my method of sticking my fingers in my ears, closing my eyes, and chanting "la-la-la-la" won't work in your case.  That is too bad.

Comment: Run TeX in nonstop mode? But I have to cite @DavidCarlisle : [people who carry on and make a pdf after an error deserve what they get](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=6365372#6365372)

Comment: Seems odd that the computation would involve too large a dimension on one run but not the next.

Comment: Well the trees usually come out with lines all over the page and with way too large bounding box in the first run. Then the lines are computed and stored and in the second run everything is fine. I guess the equivalent to la-la-la is enter-enter-enter, but it is no fun chanting all day long. =;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to disable error messages.

If you are *sure* this is the only error you're going to get and you're also sure that this doesn't really affect the typesetting on the next run, then you can launch the compilation with the

```
-interaction=nonstopmode
```

command line option, so TeX doesn't stop at the error. How to do this from a front-end/editor depends on which one you're using.